# Ember.TextArea set input through handlebars helper

Tags: binding, textarea, ember.js, helper

I got a Ember.Handlerbars.JSON helper, which formats a given value to an indented JSON string.
I'd like to set the content (value) of a textarea like this:

```
    {{#view Ember.TextArea}}
       {{JSON someValue}}
    {{/view}}
```

This does not work, since what I should set the textareas' "value" attribute instead.

However, this also doe not work

```
    {{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="JSON someValue"}}
```

Comment: What does your JSON helper look like? Can you provide a JSFiddle? You can use this as starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/eTcDu/

Comment: here it is http://jsfiddle.net/hA2A6/

Comment: Where is your JSON helper? It's not included in the sample ...

Answer (score 5):

You could solve this by using a computed property, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/3A33H/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{#with App.jsonController}}
        {{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="formatted" rows="10" }}    
    {{/with}}
</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
App = Ember.Application.create({
    formatJSON: function(obj) {
        return JSON.stringify(obj, null, '\t');
    }
});

App.jsonController = Ember.Object.create({
    content: {
        abc: 123,
        foo: 'hello'
    },

    formatted: function() {
        var obj = this.get('content');
        return App.formatJSON(obj);
    }.property('content')
});​
```

---

*Update to your comments*:

In the fiddle in the comment ( http://jsfiddle.net/4QNur/ ) your are declaring `{{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="JSON App.someComplexValue"}}`: this does not work since `valueBinding` takes a path as argument and not an expression, like `JSON App.someComplexValue`. If you want to bind to a transformed value, just create a computed property and bind to this. That's the Ember way of doing such stuff...

In your original question you have the following code:

```html
{{#view Ember.TextArea}}
    {{JSON someValue}}
{{/view}}
```

This does not work in this case, since the `value` for the `Ember.TextArea` can only be set via a `value` respectively `valueBinding`:

```html
{{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="App.controller.transformedComplexValue" }}
```

Comment: is there a way to programatically create an instance of App.JSONController in the handlebars template? like: {{#with App.JSONController someValue}}...

Comment: ahh the fiddle: [jsfiddle with JSON helper](http://jsfiddle.net/4QNur/) ... i am not very used to jsfiddle yet

Comment: You don't want to create a controller inside a handlebars template. Computed properties is the way to go...

Comment: i guess you are right. i was just to lazy to implement a proper controller for this task.